# MySQL: Check substring sequence

Tags: mysql, string, list, sequence

I have a table in MySQL with this fields SERVICE, DATE_STATE, STATE:

```
SERVICE DATE_STATE      STATE
aaaaa   '2019-12-01'    OK
aaaaa   '2019-12-03'    KO
aaaaa   '2019-12-04'    OK
...
xxxxx   '2019-12-07'    OK
xxxxx   '2019-12-09'    KO
```

The records register when the date a service change its state.

I want to check if the sequence of states is OK-KO alternately (and so on, like OK-KO-OK-KO-OK indefinitely), **when grouping by service and sorted by date**.
For example, sequence or subsequence like OK-OK or KO-KO are forbidden, and I want to check and detect them.

I don't know how to approach the solution.

With this query:

```
SELECT service, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(state ORDER BY date_state) AS sequence_state 
FROM T
group by service
```

I have in a single string the full sequence 'OK,KO,OK,KO...' but I don't know how to check the alternation in a string.

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: The `ORDER BY` definitely does not belong there in the query

Comment: Do you want to do this all in MySQL or are you also using a program language that could be used to do the checking

Comment: @RiggsFolly ,  I process the results of a simple query with Java. I map the register to POJO objects, sort the objects by date and check the states. But I want to try to do this directly with MySQL. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tests and reading, I think the right answer is:

1. If your using MySQL 8.0 or later, @cargo23's answer works perfectly.
2. It you use an older version, some *pirouette* like this must be done. After some tests, all the results were as I expected:

```
    SET @a :=0;
    SET @b :=1;
    SELECT 
        r.service, 
        r.value     AS "previous state", 
        r2.value AS "next state", 
        r.date_state    AS "date_state previous", 
        r2.date_state AS "date_state next" 
    FROM
    (SELECT if(@a, @a:=@a+1, @a:=1) as rownum, service, state as VALUE, date_state FROM services order by service ASC, date_state asc) AS r
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT if(@b, @b:=@b+1, @b:=1) as rownum, service, state as VALUE, date_state FROM services order by service ASC, date_state asc) AS r2
    ON (r.rownum+2) = r2.rownum AND r.service = r2.service 
    WHERE
    r.value IS NOT NULL 
    AND r2.value IS NOT NULL
    AND r.value = r2.value
    ORDER BY r.service ASC, r.date_state asc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I am thinking.  Try grouping by the state for all EVEN rows. If the count of the outputs is greater than 1, you know you have a problem.
Try this:

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(*)=1, 'Clear','PROBLEM') AS CheckFlag FROM (
SELECT state FROM (
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) AS seqnum
      FROM t CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0) vars
     ) t
WHERE MOD(seqnum, 2) = 0) a
GROUP BY state
) a
```

Not the best solution, but it will work!

Comment: thanks a lot, sour solution seems to be right. Two questions: 1) Could I have the service in "problem" state? Not onlyy the "global" result, but the wrong service too. 2) I'd like to understand your query better. Could you explain a little more?

Comment: Sure.  Cargo's answer is cleaner and better but with your current version, this may be an ad-hoc solution. EVEN rows should all be the same.  If they are not, you have at least one case where your state field is not alternating (repeated values).  This query selects all EVEN rows.  Then, I group by state to see if both KO and OK are in the result.  If just one is in the EVEN rows, then the Group By State would give you a COUNT of 1.  (if count(*)=1 then clear). If both are in your EVEN rows, it will give you a count of 2 because you are grouping by state and both are present.

Answer (score 1):

Using this to as sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE services (
   SERVICE varchar(50), 
   DATE_STATE date, 
   STATE varchar(2));


INSERT INTO services VALUES
  ("normal1", DATE("2000-01-01"), "OK"),
  ("normal1", DATE("2000-01-01"), "KO"),
  ("double ok", DATE("2000-01-01"), "OK"),
  ("double ok", DATE("2000-01-01"), "OK"),
  ("double ko", DATE("2000-01-01"), "KO"),
  ("double ko", DATE("2000-01-01"), "KO");
```

I created this query which gives you the desired result, using the `LEAD` window function:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 
 SERVICE, 
 DATE_STATE, 
 STATE, 
 LEAD(STATE) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY SERVICE 
          ORDER BY DATE_STATE) AS NEXT_STATE
FROM services) AS services_with_next_state
WHERE STATE=NEXT_STATE;
```

See it in action here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eMHRzJ6hN6xx4x2PjSLFXb/0

Comment: Note that window functions require MySQL 8.0 or later.

Comment: @Cargo23, thanks a lot. It can solve my problem, the SQLFiddle demo is perfect, but my MySQL version is 5.7 . What a pity!